# How to find New Four Cordingdate of image after scalling and rotation in android?

Tags: android, image, canvas, scaling

I have created a custom view for scaling and rotation of image and I need to find out the new four coordinate points. I am using the following code:

```
public class SandboxView extends View implements OnTouchListener {

    private final Bitmap bitmap;
    private final int width;
    private final int height;
    private Matrix transform = new Matrix();
    private Vector2D position = new Vector2D();
    private float scale = 1;
    private float angle = 0;
    private TouchManager touchManager = new TouchManager(2);
    private boolean isInitialized = false;
    private float degree;
    private Paint paint;
    public SandboxView(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
        super(context);
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        this.width = bitmap.getWidth();
        this.height = bitmap.getHeight();
        paint = new Paint();
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }


    private static float getDegreesFromRadians(float angle) {
        return (float)(angle * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (!isInitialized) {
            int w = getWidth();
            int h = getHeight();
            position.set(w / 2, h / 2);
            isInitialized = true;
        }
        transform.reset();
        transform.postTranslate(-width / 2.0f, -height / 2.0f);
        degree = getDegreesFromRadians(angle);
        transform.postRotate(degree);
        transform.postScale(scale, scale);
        transform.postTranslate(position.getX(), position.getY());
        float[] f = new float[9];
        transform.getValues(f);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, transform, paint);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        try {
            touchManager.update(event);
            if (touchManager.getPressCount() == 1) {
                position.add(touchManager.moveDelta(0));
            }
            else {
                if (touchManager.getPressCount() == 2) {
                    Vector2D current = touchManager.getVector(0, 1);
                    Vector2D previous = touchManager.getPreviousVector(0, 1);
                    float currentDistance = current.getLength();
                    float previousDistance = previous.getLength();
                    if (previousDistance != 0) {
                        scale *= currentDistance / previousDistance;
                    }
                    angle -= Vector2D.getSignedAngleBetween(current, previous);
                }
            }
            invalidate();
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {}
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @return image X position
     */
    public float getImageX(){
        return position.getX();
    }
    /**
     * @return image Y position
     */
    public float getImageY(){
        return position.getY();
    }
    /**
     * @return image New Height
     */
    public float getImageHeight(){
        return (scale*height);
    }
    /**
     * @return image New Width
     */
    public float getImageWidth(){
        return (scale*width);
    }
    /**
     * @return image center X
     */
    public float getBitmapCenterX(){
        return getImageX()+getImageWidth()/2;
    }
    /**
     * @return image center y
     */
    public float getBitmapCenterY(){
        return getImageY()+getImageHeight()/2;
    }

    public float getRightTopImageX(){
        return position.getX()+getImageWidth();
    }
    /**
     * @return image Y position
     */
    public float getRightTopImageY(){
        return position.getY();
    }

    public float getRightBottomImageX(){
        return position.getX()+getImageWidth();
    }
    /**
     * @return image Y position
     */
    public float getRightBottomImageY(){
        return position.getY();
    }

    public void setAngle(float angle){
        this.degree=angle;
        invalidate();
    }

    public float getAngle(){
        return degree;
    }

    public Vector2D getFirstVector(){
        return new Vector2D(position.getX(), position.getY());
    }

}
```

I need to find the four coordinates after rotation and scaling of the image.

Please help me with this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "four coordinate", but you can transform any points with method [mapPoints](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#mapPoints(float[])). Just use your Matrix object `transform`

Comment: Thanks @Robert H. My Problem is that, first i draw image on canvas, i can calculate the four codinate points of rectangle,now if i scale and rotate my rectangle(or image), i need to find out the new four points.